# How to remove all values from a dropdown than selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown. I want to remove all options from dropdown.

```
data.record.CategoryID
data.record.CategoryID
```

Here I got value for (`data.record.CategoryID`) as 3. I want to remove all options other than value 3 to remove from dropdown using jQuery.

How can I do this? The value of `data.record.CategoryID` will be change each time. So I want to remove other options than the value of `data.record.CategoryID`

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$("#your_dropdown_id").children().not(":selected").remove();
```